# Registering android system error php

Tags: php, android, mysql, authentication, web-hosting

I am trying to make an android login system and when I try to register I am getting that the user failed to store and I am not able to find the error. I am using 000webhost I don't know if it has something to do with that. Please help and thank you

I have the Internet permission, and the login is working so I think is not a problem of the connection or the database. When I try to register, the code goes to the "user failed to store" section, printing out "Unknown error occurred in registration!".

This is the register.php:

```
    <?php
    require_once 'include/DB_Functions.php';

$db = new DB_Functions();
// json response array
$response = array("error" => FALSE);

if (isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['password'])) {

    // receiving the post params
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    // check if user is already existed with the same email
    if ($db->isUserExisted($email)) {
        // user already existed
        $response["error"] = TRUE;
        $response["error_msg"] = "User already existed with " . $email;
        echo json_encode($response);
    } else {
        // create a new user
        $user = $db->storeUser($name, $email, $password);
        if ($user) {
            // user stored successfully
            $response["error"] = FALSE;
            $response["uid"] = $user["unique_id"];
            $response["user"]["name"] = $user["name"];
            $response["user"]["email"] = $user["email"];
            $response["user"]["created_at"] = $user["created_at"];
            $response["user"]["updated_at"] = $user["updated_at"];
            echo json_encode($response);
        } else {
            // user failed to store
            $response["error"] = TRUE;
            $response["error_msg"] = "Unknown error occurred in registration!";
            echo json_encode($response);
        }
    }
} else {
    $response["error"] = TRUE;

    $response["error_msg"] = "Required parameters (name, email or password) is missing!";
    echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
```

And this is the DB_Functions.php class:

```
<?php

class DB_Functions {

    private $conn;

    // constructor
    function __construct() {
        require_once 'DB_Connect.php';
        // connecting to database
        $db = new Db_Connect();
        $this->conn = $db->connect();
    }

    // destructor
    function __destruct() {

    }

    public function consigueResultado( $stmt ) {
        $RESULT = array();
        for ( $i = 0; $i < $stmt->num_rows; $i++ ) {
            $Metadata = $stmt->result_metadata();
            $PARAMS = array();
            while ( $Field = $Metadata->fetch_field() ) {
                $PARAMS[] = &$RESULT[ $i ][ $Field->name ];
            }
            call_user_func_array( array( $stmt, 'bind_result' ), $PARAMS );
            $stmt->fetch();
        }
        return $RESULT;
    }

    /**
     * Storing new user
     * returns user details
     */
    public function storeUser($name, $email, $password) {
        $uuid = uniqid('', true);
        $hash = $this->hashSSHA($password);
        $encrypted_password = $hash["encrypted"]; // encrypted password
        $salt = $hash["salt"]; // salt
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("INSERT INTO users(unique_id, name, email, encrypted_password, salt, created_at) VALUES(:uuid, :name, :email, :encrypted_password, :salt, NOW())");
        $stmt->bindParam(':uuid', $uuid);
        $stmt->bindParam(':name', $name);
        $stmt->bindParam(':email', $email);
        $stmt->bindParam(':encrypted_password', $encrypted_password);
        $stmt->bindParam(':salt', $salt);
        $result = $stmt->execute();
        //$this->conn = NULL;
        //$stmt = NULL;

        // check for successful store
        if ($result) {
            $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = :email");
            $stmt->bindParam(':email', $email);
            $stmt->execute();
            $user = $this->consigueResultado( $stmt );
            //$this->conn = NULL;
            $stmt = NULL;

            return $user;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Get user by email and password
     */
    public function getUserByEmailAndPassword($email, $password) {

        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = :email");

        $stmt->bindParam(':email', $email);

        if ($stmt->execute()) {
            $user = $this->consigueResultado( $stmt );
            //$this->conn = NULL;
            $stmt = NULL;

            return $user;
        } else {
            return NULL;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Check user is existed or not
     */
    public function isUserExisted($email) {
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT email from users WHERE email = :email");

        $stmt->bindParam(':email', $email);

        $stmt->execute();

        if ($stmt->num_rows > 0) {
            // user existed 
            //$this->conn = NULL;
            $stmt = NULL;

            return true;
        } else {
            // user not existed
            //$this->conn = NULL;
            $stmt = NULL;
            return false;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Encrypting password
     * @param password
     * returns salt and encrypted password
     */
    public function hashSSHA($password) {

        $salt = sha1(rand());
        $salt = substr($salt, 0, 10);
        $encrypted = base64_encode(sha1($password . $salt, true) . $salt);
        $hash = array("salt" => $salt, "encrypted" => $encrypted);
        return $hash;
    }

    /**
     * Decrypting password
     * @param salt, password
     * returns hash string
     */
    public function checkhashSSHA($salt, $password) {

        $hash = base64_encode(sha1($password . $salt, true) . $salt);

        return $hash;
    }

}

?>
```

Comment: You've to be more specific, what happens when you try to post using browser? does that work? use postman (a chrome/chromium app) to send post data to that url, if that works, what is the error you are getting on android device? Are you sure it's making the request? And do you have ```android.permission.INTERNET``` permission?

Comment: I have the Internet permission, and the login is working so I think is not a problem of the connection or the database. When I try to register, the code goes to the "user failed to store" section, printing out "Unknown error occurred in registration!".

Comment: can you go inside ```storeUser``` function and try debugging? check if the program flow is coming inside ```if ($result)``` block check which path is actually taken when being executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I got it to work by instead of using PDO using the deprecated version mysql. The code and the database was correct (I think), I believe that it was giving me errors because 000webhost does not support PDO or mysqli libraries.